# How to use std::partial_sum and output to a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I want an output map that has { {0,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5} }, c++11 only.  Any ideas?

```
std::map<int, int> m, out;
for( auto i=0; i < 5; ++i ) 
    m[i] = 1;

std::partial_sum( m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter( out, out.begin() ),
        []( const std::pair<int,int>& a, const std::pair<int,int>& b ) 
             { return std::pair<int,int>( a.first, a.second + b.second ); } 
);
```

This gives compile error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = int; _U2 = int; _T1 = const int; _T2 = int]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_numeric.h:295:12:   required from ‘_OutputIterator std::partial_sum(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _OutputIterator, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _OutputIterator = std::insert_iterator<std::map<int, int> >; _BinaryOperation = main()::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)>]’
../src/test_cumsum.cpp:43:130:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:188:10: error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const int, int>::first’
first = std::forward<_U1>(__p.first);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Not directly, at least.  The issue is that `std::map<int, int>::iterator::value_type` is `std::pair<const int, int>`, and that `const` prevents an object of that type from being assigned to.

--

Take a look at this [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) for `std::partial_sum`:

```cpp
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation>
constexpr // since C++20
OutputIt partial_sum(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
                     OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation op)
{
    if (first == last) return d_first;
 
    typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type sum = *first;
    *d_first = sum;
 
    while (++first != last) {
       sum = op(std::move(sum), *first); // std::move since C++20
       *++d_first = sum;
    }
    return ++d_first;
}
```

Note that `sum` gets modified each iteration by assigning the result of `op`.  Because `sum.first` is `const` that's not possible; hence the compilation error.

--

What you could do is define an iterator type that wraps `std::map::iterator` and strips out the `const`.  For example, the following will work:

```cpp
template <typename Pair>
struct RemoveFirstConstHelper
{
    using type = Pair;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct RemoveFirstConstHelper<std::pair<const T1, T2>>
{
    using type = std::pair<T1, T2>;
};

template <typename MapIterator>
class RemoveFirstConstIter
{
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = typename RemoveFirstConstHelper<typename MapIterator::value_type>::type;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    
    RemoveFirstConstIter(MapIterator it) : it_{it} {}
    
    reference operator*()
    {
        return *it_;
    }
    
    RemoveFirstConstIter& operator++()
    {
        ++it_;
        return *this;
    }
    
    RemoveFirstConstIter operator++(int) const
    {
        RemoveFirstConstIter temp{*this};
        ++temp;
        return temp;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const RemoveFirstConstIter& other) const
    {
        return it_ == other.it_;
    }
    
    bool operator!=(const RemoveFirstConstIter& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    
private:
    MapIterator it_;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b55f9e6fc04b9951)

Or you could just write your own `partial_sum` implementation for maps.  That seems like it would be simpler to me.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I see now, that keys cannot be modified in map, thus the error.  More complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: Well formatted answer with good citations. Well done.